# Print labels Java, Loops(?)

Tags: java, swing, printing, awt

I´m trying to create a application which print data in columns. My problem is that the ***job.setPrintable*** runs multiple times... This means that the document becomes totaly wrong...

Does anyone have some ideas about this?

Maybe you have some other ideas of how I can make this code better(?)...

Thank you in advanced

> I do have for example 10 indexes in my ArrayList... When I run the application, it will create 20 columns in my document... 10 of them is totaly empty and do just take up space...

```
private final int PAGE_WIDTH = Math.round(MediaSize.ISO.A4.getX(MediaSize.MM));
private final int PAGE_HEIGHT = Math.round(MediaSize.ISO.A4.getY(MediaSize.MM) / 8);
private PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
private Graphics2D column;
private Font font = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 9);

private int writeOnRow = 0;
private int pageRow = 0;
private int columnSpace = 4;
private int itemsInRow = 3;
private int itemCurrentRow = 0;

public Printer(final ArrayList<Customers> resultAsList) {
    resultAsList.remove(0);

    job.setPrintable(new Printable() {
        public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int pageIndex) throws PrinterException {
            if (pageIndex > 0) { 
                return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
            }

            column = (Graphics2D)g;
            column.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());

            column.setFont(font);

            for (Customers c : resultAsList) {
                String line =
                        c.getName() + "\n" +
                                c.getAddress() + "\n" +
                                c.getPostcode() + " " + c.getCity();

                //DATA, COLUMN, ROW
                column.drawString(c.getName(), columnSpace, writeOnRow += column.getFontMetrics().getHeight() + 2);
                column.drawString(c.getAddress(), columnSpace, writeOnRow += column.getFontMetrics().getHeight() + 2);
                column.drawString(c.getPostcode() + " " + c.getCity(), columnSpace, writeOnRow += column.getFontMetrics().getHeight() + 2);


                if (itemCurrentRow == itemsInRow) {
                    pageRow += PAGE_HEIGHT;
                    itemCurrentRow = 0;
                    columnSpace = 4;
                    itemCurrentRow++;
                } else {
                    writeOnRow = pageRow;
                    columnSpace += PAGE_WIDTH;
                    itemCurrentRow++;
                }

                writeOnRow += pageRow;
                laps++;

            }
            return PAGE_EXISTS;
        }
    });

    boolean doPrint = job.printDialog();

    if (doPrint) {
        try {
            job.print();
        } catch (PrinterException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `//Nothing to see here` actually if you face an exception you **must** see it not ignore it!

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not look clean. Sooner or later it will be very hard to maintain - actually it already is.

- It's cool that you've used all those integer values as fields, but it would be better if you make it *constants* i.e. `private static final` fields.
- Avoid creating methods that take as much as 3 arguments. It is a sign that it could be divided into smaller pieces like methods, classes, etc.
- Avoid using *magic numbers* like  `columnSpace = 4;`. What is this `4`? Consider making it a const field.
- You don't *swallow* exceptions like you did. It doesn't make sense. Either you handle them or declare `throws`.

It seems that your loop may be invalid. For making your code more pretty I recommend you read [Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882). It will make things much more clear.